# How can I tell where is the cursor on dataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using VB.Net, DataGridView.
On the image on the link, the cursor is on the third row, a user can select other rows ofcourse, how can i tell what row is curretly selected if any?

http://s30.postimg.org/5fb70arup/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_properties(v=vs.100).aspx

You would access the DataGridView.Rows collection and pass the index to it.

```
Dim RowIndex = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
MsgBox(DataGridView1.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(0).Value)
```

If you have DataGridView.MultiSelect set to true then you would just access the  items through the DataGridView.SelectedRows collection and loop through them in the collection which is 0 indexed.

```
'Loop
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    MsgBox(row.Cells(0).Value)
Next

'Or access them by index in the collection
DataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
```